# Dynamic text within ion-header-bar directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I use `ion-header-bar` directive - such that the left side is `class="button"` , the middle is `<h1>` ("Recent" word) and the right is - `<ng-icon>` .

The text on the left side is dynamically (`i18` driven)  , and it cause to the middle section to move right (if I set the left side as coast text it works well)

```
<ion-header-bar  class="bar bar-header bar-stable" no-tap-scroll="true">
    <a class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear button-positive">{{'homePage' | i18n}}
    </a>
    <h1 class="title">Recent</h1>
    <ng-icon type="messenger-left-header-icons" non-pressable="true" class="icon_plus"></ng-icon>
</ion-header-bar>
```

How it works well -

[image]

How it works bad -

[image]

How could I fix with dynamic text as well ?

Comment: you mean the h1 title?

Comment: yeap , the `h1` is the *Recent* and it got move due to its  dynamic text sibling .

Comment: you could give the button-element a fixed width

Comment: right .. looking for more generic resolve if exist ..

Comment: what happens when the h1 is too long, do you want it to wrap?

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure within header, enlose left and right buttons or icons.

```
<ion-header-bar  class="bar bar-header bar-stable" no-tap-scroll="true">
  <div class="buttons">
      <a class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear button-positive">{{'homePage' | i18n}}</a> 
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Recent</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <ng-icon type="messenger-left-header-icons" non-pressable="true" class="icon_plus"></ng-icon>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```